# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Speaker Recognition API - Verification - error-SpeakerInvalid

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services, voice-recognition

I am still facing the error in the verification process

**{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"SpeakerInvalid"}}'**

My audio is correct as it is getting enrolled easily

```
##code for API CALL speaker verification 

import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
subscription_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

headers = {
# Request headers
"Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key,
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'verificationProfileId':'445b849b-6418-4443-961b-77bd88196223',

})

#body = {
#}
try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('speaker-recognition-api.cognitiveservices.azure.com')
    body = open('pp.wav','rb') //pp.wav is my audio file
    conn.request("POST", "/spid/v1.0/verify?verificationProfileId=445b849b-6418-4443-961b-77bd88196223?%s" % params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem. You are getting this error cause there is a `?` in the end of your url, however behind `verify` there is already a `?`. So if you want to add params to your request url you should use `&` just like the sample code in this API doc:[Speaker Recognition - Verification](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549d) .

[image]

Below is my work code.

```
try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('geospeaker.cognitiveservices.azure.com')


    body=open("output4.wav","rb")
    conn.request("POST", "/spid/v1.0/verify?verificationProfileId=1ae143b0-c301-4345-9295-3e34ad367092?%s" % params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except OSError as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code for speaker-identification and specific audio length.

sometime i get the error 
b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Audio too short"}}'
b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Audio too long"}}'

Comment: The audio file should be at least 1-second-long and no longer than 15 seconds. Check the api request body description.https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549d

Comment: Help me i am facing this issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525533/microsoft-cognitive-services-speaker-recognition-api-identification-error

Comment: Cause I don't get this error, so would you mind share your wav file I will have a test later.

Comment: i am not getting this error in verification but in identification, I am getting

please also let me know how you are recording the audio (which software/command)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15QNqAg5TBxlPUG0PLb4Nda_jDAOHuxzU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My audio length is 35 seconds:
what this says 
<_io.BufferedReader name='pkk.wav'>
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fd2604e4e90>
b''

Comment: Actually I use [text2speech](https://www.text2speech.org/) to get the audio, cause it's used to do test.

Comment: can you please share the code for speaker identification code it's request, please

Comment: I just use the sample code in the api [doc](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549d).  And the code in the office pc.

Comment: the code you have given is for verification and its working fine but i am facing the issue in identification